# Why my freeform ModalViewController always show full size?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

iOS7 and xCode5.

I created a `UIViewController` with XIB,

1, I unchecked the option "Use Autolayout";
2, Changed the Size to "Freeform";
3, Changed Status Bar to "None".

then I resized my view in xib (such like [280, 110]), but when I show the viewcontroller,

```
MyViewController *sellDialog = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        [self presentViewController:MyDialog animated:YES completion:^{

        }];
```

the view always full screen size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choosing the "Freeform" option in the storyboard is only a "Simulated metric". When you present a view controller modally on iPhone, it will always appear full screen.

If you wanted to display your view controller over another view controller and have it not be full screen, you would need to come up with another solution. On iPhone, you would probably have to implement your own container view controller that shows the second view controller in a smaller frame. On iPad, you could show your view controller in a `UIPopoverController`.

Comment: You could try searching Google for "container view controller tutorial" and you should be able to find something. Otherwise, googling for just "container view controller" should at least give you examples and other relevant information for creating one.

Comment: To whoever down voted my answer here, that I posted more than 3.5 years ago, would you please provide some rationale for your down vote? If you feel my answer is incorrect for some reason, please let me know. Also take into account when it was posted, in case you feel this became not true at some point since then, and maybe feel free to post your own more current answer, not down vote mine. Also I believe it does still correctly answer the question.